# Showing the loading spinner icon on all components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have written the code to show the loading spinner on all components when any event is triggered. It works fine on a single component but the issue with it, I have to show the same loading spinner on the around multiple components when certain event is triggered. See below code:

```
  tasks() {
  this.handler.activateLoader();
  this.tasksService.get(this.page, this.pageSize).subscribe(results => {
    this.handler.hideLoader();
    if (this.handler.handle(results)) {
      return;
    }
    this.tasksRes = results['data'];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.tasksRes.length; i++) {
      if (this.tasksRes[i].status == 'In_progress' && this.tasksRes[i].eventType == 'Sync' &&
        this.tasksRes[i].entityId == this.id) {
        this.progressFlag = true;
        break;
      } else {
        this.progressFlag = false;
      }
    }
    this.length = results['totalElements'];
  }, error => {
    this.handler.hideLoader();
    this.handler.error(error);
  });
}

connect() {
  let source = new EventSource('/api/v1/events/register');
  source.addEventListener('message', message => {
    this.tasks();
  });
}
```

And on ngOnInit(), I have called these 2 methods as below then its working fine.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.tasks();
  this.connect();
}
```

The actual requirement is when I run a particular event the button is going to be disabled and at the same time the spinner loading will come. I have achieved this one. But how to show the same spinner on multiple components so that the user can know that the task is running.

This is how I am showing the loading spinner. See below:

```
<span class="text-warning pull-right" *ngIf="progressFlag">
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
</span>
```

In my code, I have many components at around 17-18 where I need to show the loading spinner. If I want to show the spinner globally means I can show it on either header and footer component which is common to my entire template. Can any one provide any ideas on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please search keyword HttpInterceptor learn details. One simple example below:

```
// siteHttpInterceptor.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoadingService } from './loading.service';

@Injectable()
export class SiteHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService){}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, httpHandler: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
      /* Start loading here */
      this.loadingService.startLoading();
      return httpHandler.handle(request).pipe(
          tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
              /* End loading */
              this.loadingService.endLoading();
          },
          (err: any) => {
              /* End loading */
              this.loadingService.endLoading();
          }),
          catchError(err => {
              return throwError(err);
          })
      );
  }
}

//loading.service.ts LoadingService base on Ionic framework, you can instead it
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {

  private loaders = [];
  //sometimes, the request so quickly then close event earlier than open loading bar
  private badLoaders = 0;

  constructor(
      private loadingController: LoadingController
  ) {
  }

  async startLoading() {
      if (this.badLoaders > 0) {
          this.badLoaders --;
      } else {
          await this.loadingController.create({
              message: 'Loading ...',
          }).then(loader => {
              this.loaders.push(loader);
              loader.present().then(() => {
                  //if it is bad loader, close
                  if (this.badLoaders > 0) {
                      this.badLoaders --;
                      this.endLoading();
                  }
              });
          });
      }
  }

  endLoading() {
      let loader = this.loaders.pop();
      if (loader) {
          loader.dismiss();
      } else {
          // it is mean close event earlier
          this.badLoaders ++;
      }
  }

}
```

Use it then you not need manage loader handle each request method.

Comment: Loader doesn't always work only for HTTP request - be generic with your answer

Comment: @RahulSwamynathan of course, you can build one service and define one subject there, same time subscribe it in your loader, and at other component, call service.subject.next('open'/'close').

Answer (score 0):

Put your spinner at the main component.. in most cases its the AppComponent

Then put a these on your shared service

```
 private LoadingStatus = new Subject<boolean>();

 // Observable string streams
 IsLoading$ = this.LoadingStatus.asObservable();

 // Service message commands
 triggerLoading(status: boolean) {
   this.LoadingStatus.next(mission);
 }
```

Then at your sender component call `triggerLoading(true)` or `triggerLoading(false)` from the service and subscribe at your main component (AppComponent):

```
this.shareService.IsLoading$.subscribe( data => progressFlag = data )
```

Or Add your logic as this:

```
this.shareService.IsLoading$.subscribe(
 data => {
   if(data) {
     // start loading logic here
   } else {
     // end loading logic here
   }
 }
)
```

Source: [Angular - Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)